# SpringBoot Maven build fails

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm new to maven. However, I'm trying to use Gitlab CI Runner for automated testing and building / deployment.

I got my current maven configuration from a colleague of mine.

When ever a job runs, it fails after a couple of seconds with following error message:

```
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-bom/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-security-bom-4.2.3.RELEASE.pom (5 KB at 101.0 KB/sec)
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-processor:jar is missing. @ line 20, column 21
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project de.demo:Rest:2.0 (/builds/Dev/Demo/Restv2/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-processor:jar is missing. @ line 20, column 21
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Here are my spring dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-processor</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android.json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I appreciate any help, I couldn't find a solution for my error :/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct artifact name for "spring-boot-starter-processor"? The closest match I've found on mvn repository is "spring-boot-configuration-processor" (https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=spring-boot-starter-processor). If this is the correct name - the error says it all - you are missing the <version> tag for this dependency to determine the version of the artifact you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean

```
<!-- 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot
-configuration-processor -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

not `spring-boot-starter-processor`, check it out here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/1.5.9.RELEASE

Comment: thank you very much it works now, as I said it was a dependency I got from a colleague and I've nver thought it was a non existing dependency... :/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the root issue you are having is attempting to use a dependency that does not exist (`spring-boot-starter-processor` from `org.springframework.boot`). Fixing the dependency name to the one that is actualy defined in your parent - `spring-boot-starter-parent` will also fix your "version" problem.

The error you are seeing is saying a different thing (no version defined) because each maven dependency needs to have a version defined directly or in the dependency management. Since you have set up `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent, it uses dependency versions for all *valid* dependencies from there.

If for any reason this is a correct dependency name (which would be very strange), you will fix the error by properly defining the version, like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-processor</artifactId>
    <version>(insert version here)</version>
</dependency>
```

or via dependency management: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

Comment: Thank you very much! As I said in my comment above: I'd never thought it would be because of a non existing dependency... :/ anyway, it works now!